# Scroll the uiview and make visible to the user

Tags: iphone, uiview

MainView
- UIScrollView
  - View 1
  - View 2
  - View 3
  - View 4
  - View 5
  - View 6 (contains button)

When i click button in view6 i need to scroll the screen top and show the view3 to user in iPhone.

Comment: First show some code which you have did it.

Comment: All views are in same viewController ?

Answer (score 0):

For that you just set the frame of scroll view for third view.Use this line of code I think this will work for you.try this.Set all this according to your coordinates

```
 self.scrollview.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```